# Polymer 2 pass Dynamic text into Slot

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x

I want to pass trough a property into a child component via a slot, basically expecting the text to be rendered and passed through, so ideally having to do nothing in the child component

Parent

```
<span slot="dialog__slot-heading">[[_headerText]]</span>

_headerText: {
  type: String,
  computed: '_computeHeaderText(activeMaturity.row.target)',
},
```

Child

```
<h3 class="dialog__heading"><slot name="dialog__slot-heading"></slot></h3>
```

However at the moment nothing gets rendered, any help appreciated

Comment: You need to use double braces {{_headerText}} so that polymer will listen for changes and do update. You can also set notify:true under properties.

Answer (score 1):

Your question might be missing some relevant code to reproduce the problem, but here's a demo of what you're trying to achieve:

#### Using [named slots](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/slot#Use_%3Cslot%3E_in_%3Ctemplate%3E_to_make_a_doc_fragment_with_named_slots) with Polymer:

1. From your parent element, declare the `<span>` in the light DOM of the child element. Give the `<span>` a named slot (e.g., `dialog__slot-heading` in this case).

   ```
   <dom-module id="x-parent">
     <template>
       <x-child>
         <span slot="dialog__slot-heading">[[_headerText]]</span>
       </x-child>
     </template>
   </dom-module>
   ```
2. From your child element, declare a `<slot name="FOO">` with `FOO` replaced with the name you selected in step 1:

   ```
   <dom-module id="x-child">
     <template>
       <slot name="dialog__slot-heading">Default Child Heading</slot>
     </template>
   </dom-module>
   ```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/oGPMGJ?editors=1010)